# Run Kubernetes locally and connect to remote Docker server

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-machine

I want to run my docker containers on a remote server, because my machine isn't powerful enough.

I have [setup a Hetzner server with `docker-machine`](https://github.com/JonasProgrammer/docker-machine-driver-hetzner) and have successfully switched to that docker server. Docker commands are now executed on my Hetzner machine.

I'd like to expand this setup to be able to run Kubernetes on this remote docker server.

Is that possible? Do I need to install Kubernetes on the VM running on Hetzner or can I run a local Kubernetes instance that simply uses the remote server?

I'd like my setup to be as close as possible to a local installation.

Comment: At this level, Kubernetes and Docker are pretty different.  If you set up Kubernetes, you should not expect to be able to interact with it using `docker` commands at all.  How are you hoping to be able to use the remote system; are you just making calls to services' published ports, or is it more involved?

Comment: Well basically I have a few pods installed, with services that interact and expose a few http services. I'm not intending to interact with docker commands, but I thought that kubernetes was basically a management tool for docker containers, that's why I thought I could use a remote docker server like that?

Comment: Could you elaborate more about the question? What exactly do you want to achieve? What is your local k8s setup, minikube? You would have to install kubernetes on this remote docker server, for example there is something called [kind](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind) which I would recommend to use here.  `I want to run my docker containers ` as @DavidMaze mentioned Kubernetes and Docker are pretty different. In short, Docker helps to “create” containers(image), and Kubernetes allows you to “manage” them at runtime(run and expose deployment with image created with docker).

Comment: I was hoping that I could simply run a kubernetes cluster locally that connects to a remote docker-machine, but I have since realised that kubernetes needs to be running on the remote machine in order to be accessible from my local setup.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes requires a control-plane (at least one server) and agent 'machines' (at least one). For a full installation it also requires an etcd database. For a minimum production configuration you'll need at least 9 separate servers.

Having said that, you can just run [Rancher's K3D](https://k3d.io/) on the remote machine, which like [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/) and [Kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) (and others), is a kubernetes installation that runs in docker on a single machine. Personally, I think K3D is the best option, but opinions vary. Be aware though that the resources required to run kubernetes are quite high, and the server you rent should have sufficient power. For a simple learning type workload I'd recommend at least 2 cores and 8gb of ram.

There are many ways to configure this and access it from your local machine. You'll need to open ports on the remote control-plane to allow access from your local, but it sounds like you've already done that for docker so you should be able to do it for kubernetes. You'll also need to use `kubectl`, but it's best to run that in a docker container, rather than installing it locally.

Answer (score -1):

The way I understand it, it's not as easy as that. Some Kubernetes worker must be installed on the remote machine in order for my local Kubernetes server to be able to use it.

The easiest solution for me will be to rent a complete Kubernetes cluster from Digital Ocean or Google and use that. It's more expensive, but it will be the least amount of effort to get it running.

Another solution would be to install a full Kubernetes setup (with Minikube for example) on the remote machine, and use it via SSH.

Comment: For someone asking questions at this level, renting a k8s cluster from gcp or d-o is far from the easiest thing to do, and also far from cost-effective as a learning platform.